# Cakephp 2.6: How to get role from associative table in cakephp Auth

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have a table name `users`, which has a relation with `user_types`. User types table has a field name `role`. I need this role field by Auth component. So I have tried like

```
$type = $this->Auth->user(['Usertype']['name']);
```

Here I get notice name is undefined. I can get this data add another query and set it in session. My question is, is it possible to get it by cakephp Auth component ?

like we can get Auth username by below code

```
$this->Auth->user('username');
```

Same thing is it possible for associative data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
$type = $this->Auth->user('Usertype.name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are naming the tables correctly but not models. Corresponding model for `user_types` table is `UserType`. If you set up correct associations (this means your `users` table should have field named like `user_type_id`), you should get it like this:

```
  $this->Auth->user('UserType.name');
```

More on naming [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions).